# Access to spreadsheet in deployed web app

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, null, typeerror

I am trying to access a Google spreadsheet via a Google script, that is published as a web app.

How I created the script:

- from the spreadsheet, Tools/Script editor..., Spreadsheet project
- and it asked for access to the spreadsheets in GDrive, so overall I assume it is attached to the spreadsheet.

The script:

```
function doGet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  // alternative, doesn't work either
  // var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/abcdef/edit");
  
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();

  var text = ... loop over sheets and do some stuff to get the data ...

  return ContentService.createTextOutput(text);
}
```

The error message when calling the web app:

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getSheets" of null.

The function works (minus the `ContentService.createTextOutput` of course) when run in the editor.

Comment: [According to Google](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound), it is "uncommon" for bound scripts to be deployed as Web Apps. It appears that being deployed in this way prevents the script from accessing `getActiveSpreadsheet()`, etc methods. This makes more sense if we consider `getActiveSheet()` -- there is no concept of "active sheet" in the context of a web app. So it seems you need to open a sheet by name (or number) and a spreadsheet by URL or Id.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use the getActive() method unless the script is bound to a spreadsheet (ie script was created within the spreadsheet).

In your example with openByUrl() I would check your URL and the permissions to that sheet. Here is working example of what you were trying to do.

```
function doGet(){
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XLOVvEo2nzLARwRhsiWUrFMtF0LnofC1PQoWIeLmwgQ/edit#gid=0');
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(ss.getSheets()[0].getName()).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT); 
}
```

Comment: Alright, the openByUrl example works now. I swear I had it like that before ;-) And that's pretty okay. But I have created the script from within the spreadsheet as stated in my initial post. So SpreadsheetApp.getActive() should return the spreadsheet, even when called in doGet(), right? Or is there maybe another method to call when the UI is not visible? (which is probably the case, considering the scope of the web app)

Comment: I'm also trying to figure this out. According to the docs, getActive should work in the deployed web app but it definitely is not working for me either.

Comment: Which page in the docs says getActive should work? I'll put in a ticket to get that fixed. It will not work unless you set the active with setActive or the script is launched from the doc.